# How can I remove the "updates" menu in the Wordpress Admin panel?

Tags: admin, menus

How can I remove the "updates" menu in the Wordpress Admin panel?

[Picture 1.png http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/5135/picture1pv.png](http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/5135/picture1pv.png)

Comment: The needed solution depends of what you want to achieve. Just removing it from display could be done via a php global variable, css and jQuery. Just removing it would still leave it accessible. Completely denying the access to a user is bit more complicated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`remove_submenu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_submenu_page) function:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_38111' );
function wpse_38111() {
    remove_submenu_page( 'index.php', 'update-core.php' );
}
```